# Conditions for the constants to make system consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

new to this Stack Exchange, but I'm sure it will be just as helpful as the others!

I'm just a little bit confused with this problem. The problem is determine all conditions for which the constants $\alpha$, $\beta,$ and $\gamma$ must satisfy in order for the system below to be consistent.

$x+2y+2z=\alpha$

$2x+5y+7z=\beta$

$3x+3y-3z=\gamma$

I put that into an augmented matrix and ended with the reduced row echelon form below

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&-7\alpha+2\beta+\frac{4\gamma}{3} \\ 0&1&0&7\alpha-2\beta-\gamma \\ 0&0&1&-3\alpha+\beta+\frac{\gamma}{3} \end{bmatrix}
$$

But I am not sure how to answer the question they asked. I looked over some other similar questions but they all had a row that was $0=$ some constant(s), for example, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232684/what-conditions-must-the-constants-satisfy-so-that-each-of-these-systems-has-a-s)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  the vectors $\vec a =(1,2,2),\vec b = (2,5,7),\vec c=(3,3,-3)$ are linearly dependent.  If you can find a non-trivial relation between them, your variables will have to satisfy that as well.

Comment: Hint: for the system of equations to have a solution, the vector $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)^T$ must be an element of the column space of the coefficient matrix. You ended up with a pivot in every row. What does that say about the column space?

Comment: @lulu I appreciate the hints, but I still don't understand

Comment: @amd Also appreciate your hint, but am only allowed to mention one user per comment

Comment: Can you find a non-trivial relation between those three vectors?

Comment: Double-check your row reduction, by the way. I get a rather different result.

Comment: @amd Thanks I will redo it now

Comment: @amd I'm such a tart, in the first operation I added first row to third -3 times and somehow got -3+(-6) = -6. Now it is much like the example I linked, so thank you!

Comment: You should update your question with the correction.